# Entity Framework Generated SQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Is it possible to output the SQL generated by the Entity Framework on a global level and not on a query by query basis?  I'm looking to just dump it all somewhere so I can review it.

If that is not possible, how do I view the SQL being generated for updates and inserts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want [**LinqPad**](http://www.linqpad.net/), here are **[some videos](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/LinqPad)** that show you how to use it

Comment: LINQPad is great for selects, but I need this for all transactions (i.e. select, insert, update, delete) – Matthew 5 mins ago

Comment: LINQPad does all of those as well, just checked myself

Comment: Thank you, I see that now.  I was hoping for a different solution  but this will work.

Answer (score 7):

The [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) will allow you to view the commands that are being executed on the server while the application is running.

Another free tool for profiling SQL Server 2005 Express [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1459).

### UPDATE

Another method to see what is being generated by LINQ is the Log property of the DataContext.

It is a TextWriter that should be easy to save the contents to a file or redirect to Console.Out.

[MSDN Info for Log property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx)

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to output to a file or view the SQL in Visual Studio and avoid having to run profiler or use an additional tool.

Comment: LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework are not the same.  Entity Framework context does not have this option.

Comment: Nice, never knew that about L2S, just another reason I'm glad I went with it over EF :)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an answer to this too. It turns out there is a pretty nifty way to view the EF-generated SQL, if you don't mind dipping into the somewhat-sketchy world of reflection.

A very resourceful poster on the MSDN forums wrote a set of extension methods that let you dump the SQL output of an `ObjectContext` (i.e. the stuff that will get executed when you call `SaveChanges()`).

You can find the link [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/2a50ffd2-ed73-411d-82bc-c9c564623cb4/) - look for the post by g_yordanov containing the CustomExtensions class.

I have been testing this out over the past little while and it seems to do the trick quite nicely. The one catch is that I had to make the fix suggested by David Cater in that thread - changing the `Dictionary<long, object>` to a `Dictionary<int, object>`.

Answer (score 1):

Since this was originally asked, you can also now use [EFProf](http://efprof.com/) to profile your Entity Framework application, which allows you to see the SQL Generated among many other metrics.

Comment: EFProf is commercial software.

Comment: Do developers not use commercial software now?